# Load files with certain names in R

Tags: r, file, load

I have thousands of files, but I only want to load some of them, those I want to load all are all named "xxxx5429.spe" e.i the all have the same ending, is there a easy way to do it?

Comment: You could start with `list.files()`. For more, see e.g. http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/list.files.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess those `x`'s are meant to be wildcards. Also guessing they are meant to be exactly 4 characters wide. If my guesses are both correct then probably can be handled witha regex pattern like:

```
 patt= ".{4}5429[.]spe"
```

The `list.files` function can handle a regex pattern to its second argument. The first argument needs to be a path. Or you can do this just in the working directory if you name the argument:

```
 my_files <- list.files(patt= ".{4}5429[.]spe")
```

It's not exactly clear what you mean by "load files". The term `load` in R generally applies to a package or a .Rdata file. If these are text files then one of the `read*` functions would be used: the readLines function if the text is unstructured,  or one of the variants of the read.table function if the files are rectangular and delimited files.

This would create a list object containing character vectors with the contents of such files (from the working directory)  using `readLines`:

```
  my_files <- lapply( my_files, readLines)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I seen that I was not very clear when I wrote the question, but I got it to work.